# input type=file click not triggered when called from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-framework-7

I am running into a weird problem. Not sure if it is due to the security concern of any other reason. I have following piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button onclick='someThgTemp()'>TRY</button><br /><br /><br /><br />
<label id='labelId' for='some'>sdfasdf</label>
<input id='some' type='file'/>
</body>
<script>
var someThg = function someThg(){
alert(2);
console.log(document.getElementById('labelId'));
  document.getElementById('labelId').click();
}

function someThgTemp(someThg){
alert('1');
var that = this;
  window.setTimeout(function(){

  that.someThg();
 }, 3000)

alert(3)

}
</script>
</html>
```

So on this line:

```
<button onclick='someThgTemp()'>TRY</button>
```

the file chooser dialog is not shown

Where as if I change the above line to following

```
<button onclick='someThg()'>TRY</button>
```

The file chooser is called.Please let me know what I am doing wrong and what is the alternative for it.

The reason to do this being, before showing the file browser I need to validate something. If validated then only I want to show the user file browser.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are clicking on the label instead of input? And you are screwing up `this` and `that`?

Comment: No . Thats not the issue. Even If I trigger click on input also it wont work. Since the type="file"

Comment: @NitinMesta Works perfectly in my answer. Check it out. Let me know if you cannot use this for some reason, would love to debug more.

Comment: @NitinMesta Works in both the anonymous function as well as timer function as well as button click function.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I will check and let you know.

Comment: Just curious to know, if you are able to achieve what you wanna get by running the two snippets in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you can not trigger manually a click event that open popup or open a dialog file in asynchronous call with too much delay (`setTimeout` use after 3 seconds). The user must associate directly the click to the event that you want that happens.

Try to set 1000 milliseconds instead of 3000. (and delete all alerts)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are messing up with `this` and `that`. I would go ahead in this way:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  theBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  theBtn.onclick = function () {
    theFile = document.getElementById("some");
    theFile.click();
  };
};
```

```html
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button id="myBtn">TRY</button>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<label id='labelId' for='some'>sdfasdf</label>
<input id='some' type='file' />
```

Using a Timer - Browse window comes after a second.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  theBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  theTimeFunc = function () {
    theFile = document.getElementById("some");
    theFile.click();
  };
  theBtn.onclick = function () {
    setTimeout(theTimeFunc, 1000);
  };
};
```

```html
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button id="myBtn">TRY</button>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<label id='labelId' for='some'>sdfasdf</label>
<input id='some' type='file' />
```

Comment: Try to set 3000 on timeout instead of 1000, in your code

Comment: @chumkiu Eh... It doesn't work. `:o`

Comment: it's the same problem of OP. Its code is right, the problem is only on delay after the user interaction

Comment: @chumkiu Do we have any solid reason? But we can do it using multiple timeouts. Or chaining functions or callback functions.

Comment: My Firefox says that has prevent a popup open. So I think it's a rule of anti popup. The same happens with window.open. However I have no reference ready to link now. Just experience. If I found something i would happy to post it

Comment: @chumkiu Na... This is not related to popup... This is a crazy security ****.

Comment: That's what firefox explicity says.

Comment: @PraveenKumar as chumkiu said if the time out is more then call is not triggered. Do you guys have alternative solutions? as the code I had pasted above is just a sample and my actual anonymous function may take more time in real as there will be user interaction. Please suggest

Comment: @NitinMesta Chaining timeouts... `:D`

Comment: But I cannot do that. I have a Helper method call which will handle the thing and call my callback once done :P

Comment: before `theFile.click()` row, add  `var d = +new Date(); while(+new Date() - d <= 2000) {};`. But I've never say that.

Comment: @chumkiu ... And screw up the browser. :D